# If you wish + comma?

Tags: commas, conditionals

Would you place a comma in the following sentence ?

"If you wish to confirm, please send us a deposit".

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U, @Xalef.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

> If you wish to confirm, please send us a deposit

You would omit the comma if the conditional clause were at the end.

> Please send us a deposit if you wish to confirm.

Comment: This may well be correct but is an unsatisfactory answer for SE EL&U because you only express an opinion, providing neither argument or evidence in support. How is the poster or anyone else to know whether or not your answer is correct?

Comment: It [says](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), "Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful... but fuller explanations are better." Feel free to add your own competing answer.